# What is the cleanest way of running multiple variable=function() and knowing when they are all complete

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have multiple variables that need calculating before being saved as as JSON file, these are calculated with a function. However when running asynchronously they come up as undefined. I read up on promises and seems like this may be the way, but it seems a bit silly running 15 promises, so I thought I'd ask if there is a cleaner way of doing this. Here's a portion of the code

```js
var sql = "Select a.Volume, a.LastPrice, a.buyers, a.id From (Select Volume, LastPrice, buyers, id FROM "+ marketname +" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1440) a order by a.id asc";
          db.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          result.forEach(function(element){
            results = result.length;
            tempArrayVol.push(element.Volume);
            tempArrayPrice.push(element.LastPrice);
            tempArrayBuyers.push(element.buyers);
            counter++;
            console.log(results + " " + counter);
          });
          
         var volumeaverage = (( tempArrayVol.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }) )  / tempArrayVol.length);
         var buyersaverage = ((( tempArrayBuyers.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; }) ) / tempArrayBuyers.length ) * 100);

         var price24h    = change(prevDay, tempArrayPrice[tempArrayPrice.length -1]);
          //etc
```

So once all variables are defined, the JSON file should be written, should I chain promises or is there a better way?

Comment: If you run them all as `Promises` and then pass them into [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) it should be relatively clean, I think...

Comment: Do you have 15 different queries? Why 15 promises?

Comment: This is JS, you have to live with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

```
Promise.all([
  function1(),
  function2(),
  function3(),
]).then(([res1, res2, res3]) => doSomething(res1,res2,res3));
```

[`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```
async function() {
  const res1 = await func1();
  const res2 = await func2();
  const res3 = await func3();
  // do your thing
}
```

Comment: You mean `.then([res1, res2, res3] => doSomething(res1, res2, res3`

Comment: Or shorter `.then(allRes => doSomething(...allRes)`